# Help in partial differential coefficient.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, chain-rule

This might sound silly,but i am somewhat stucked :

If $\eta=\eta(x,y)$ and $\tau=\tau(x,y)$

$$p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}$$

$$q=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial y}$$
Then i have to find $r=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}$

Consider the first part of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(p)$ 
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{\partial z}{\partial n} \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}\bigg)=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial \eta^2}\bigg(\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}\bigg)^2+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 \eta}{\partial x^2}$$

I feel i am making some mistake here,as 
The answer given is

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{\partial z}{\partial n} \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}\bigg)=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial \eta^2}\bigg(\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}\bigg)^2+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 \eta}{\partial x^2}+
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial \eta \partial \tau}\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial x}\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}
$$

Can anyone point out where this extra term came from ?

the other part will rely upon the correctness of this,pointing out the mistake in this part will help.

Comment: Just a suggestion, applying the chain rule with Jacobian matrices might be easier...

Comment: can you please elaborate,jacaobian of what ? (I mean like $\frac{\partial (f_1,f_2)}{\partial (x_1,x_2)}$ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the product rule we obtain:
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{\partial z}{\partial n} \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}\bigg)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta} \right)\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} \right).$$

Applying the chain rule we have: 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta} \right) = \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta}\right)+\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta}\right)\tag{1}$$
and from that you obtain the expected result.

Let me be more explicit on the calculation of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta} \right)$.
We are thinking of $z$ as a function on the variables $(\eta,\tau)$. Besides that, $\eta$ and $\tau$ are functions of $x$ and $y$. Now, the same happens to $f(\eta,\tau) := \frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta}$. The function $f$ depends on $(\eta,\tau)$. Applying the Chain Rule we obtain:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}+\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau}. \tag{2}$$

The expression $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $ is a shorter way of writting
$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left[f(\eta(x,y),\tau(x,y))\right] $.

So, putting $f= \frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta}$ on the equation $(2)$ we obtain the equation $(1)$.

Comment: Can u explain a bit why $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta} \right) = \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta}\right)+\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta}\right)$ ?

Comment: Hi! I added some detail to my answer. I hope it's is clearer now.